# How will codename application keep running at backend even if we close the gui interface

Tags: codenameone

How can we run application at backend even if the application in android or i-phone is closed

Comment: Do you want the app or your server to perform some background activities?

Comment: Client only to update information from server

Answer (score 1):

You could perform a [BackgroundFetch](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/background/BackgroundFetch.html), but it's not guaranteed to always be active due to OS limitation and ability to manually turn the feature off by a user.

```
public class MyApplication implements BackgroundFetch {

    @Override
    public void performBackgroundFetch(long deadline, Callback<Boolean> onComplete) {
        //perform the background activity here
        onComplete.onSucess(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

You can find a sample demo code [here](https://gist.github.com/codenameone/ecccc5c6452d055359f12374b2db2644).